# Device for image sensing and processing

Tags: image-processing

I need a device which can sense the images which crosses it and feeds it into a bigger display. It must be cost efficient and good working.

I don't know what to use for the device but i am planning in using a big led display.

Comment: Hi and welcome. In it's current form I'm afraid this question isn't suitable as it's not related to a programming challenge and it is also asking for a product recommendation. (feel free to try the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an idea of would be a better suited question here). It would be great if you explain what you mean by image crossing a device ? Are you talking about an LED processor that can take a video signal (HDMI/DP/etc.) and send to a big LED display ? Does this process involve code ?(Is the image generated in a real-time engine for example) ?

Comment: Please follow George's advice and rewrite your question to be more specific. That said, if I understood your question, you might try a Raspberry Pi + compatible camera + display. But you should rewrite your post, ask a single question, and follow other guidelines. Good luck!